# Raspberry pi cmake file usage problem in vscode c++

Tags: c++, cmake

I want to include the library named rpi-rgb-matrix in my VSCode C++ Project.

But I need to convert the ready Makefile to Cmake file I did it

Unfortunately I am getting the error I mentioned.

Please help with Cmake

```
**Target Library :** https://github.com/hzeller/rpi-rgb-led-matrix
```

**Error Code :**

```
build] /home/pi/new_kickass/matrix/lib/led-matrix.cc: In constructor ‘rgb_matrix::RGBMatrix::Options::Options()’:
[build] <command-line>: error: ‘regular’ was not declared in this scope
[build] /home/pi/new_kickass/matrix/lib/led-matrix.cc:270:20: note: in expansion of macro ‘DEFAULT_HARDWARE’
[build]    hardware_mapping(DEFAULT_HARDWARE),
[build]                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

**My CMAKE**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16.3)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
project(kickass)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -DDEFAULT_HARDWARE=regular")
include_directories(Libs)
include_directories(Include)
include_directories(matrix/lib)
include_directories(matrix/include)

file(GLOB_RECURSE SRC_FILES Libs/*.cpp)
file(GLOB_RECURSE HEADER_FILES Include/*.h)
file(GLOB_RECURSE RGB_SRC_FILES matrix/lib/*.cc)
file(GLOB_RECURSE RGB_HEADER_FILES matrix/include/*.h)


add_executable(kickass main.cpp ${HW_HEADER_FILEs} ${RGB_SRC_FILES} ${RGB_HEADER_FILES} ${SRC_FILES} ${HEADER_FILES})

target_link_libraries(kickass -lpthread curl )
```

**MY main.CPP**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "led-matrix.h"
#include "pixel-mapper.h"
#include "graphics.h"
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <limits.h>
#include "gpio.h"
using rgb_matrix::GPIO;
using rgb_matrix::Canvas;
using rgb_matrix::FrameCanvas;
using rgb_matrix::RGBMatrix;

using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  rgb_matrix::RuntimeOptions runtime_opt;
  RGBMatrix::Options matrix_options;
  matrix_options.hardware_mapping="regular";
  matrix_options.cols=64;
  matrix_options.rows=128;
  matrix_options.disable_hardware_pulsing=1;
  runtime_opt.gpio_slowdown=3;
Canvas *canvas = RGBMatrix::CreateFromFlags(&argc, &argv, &matrix_options);
if (canvas == NULL)
    return 1;
    cout << "Merhaba Dünya Ben Geldim" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The project's [Makefile](https://github.com/hzeller/rpi-rgb-led-matrix/blob/master/lib/Makefile#L166) defines the macro `DEFAULT_HARDWARE` as a **string literal** `"regular"`, not as a *plain* word `regular` as you do.

Comment: Same again... :(

Comment: Assuming you have modified the macro definition properly, the error message cannot be the **same**.

Comment: [build] /home/pi/new_kickass/lib/led-matrix.cc: In constructor ‘rgb_matrix::RGBMatrix::Options::Options()’:
[build] <command-line>: error: ‘regular’ was not declared in this scope
[build] /home/pi/new_kickass/lib/led-matrix.cc:270:20: note: in expansion of macro ‘DEFAULT_HARDWARE’
[build]    hardware_mapping(DEFAULT_HARDWARE),

Comment: The message "<command-line>: error: ‘regular’ was not declared in this scope" means that you still define `DEFAULT_HARDWARE` as a plain word `regular`. Try `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -DDEFAULT_HARDWARE=\"regular\"")`.